# Jquery - loading an html menu with jquery breaks the responsive dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am loading a menu into my HTML page using this simple function
    `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some-menu').load('menu.html');
    $('#some-footer').load('footer.html')
    });`

it works fine but on responsive view it breaks the bootstrap dropdowns. Does anyone have a quick fix or solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap, which it sounds like you are, I'd look at the following...

Menu Details:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Dropdown Details:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns